# Double partition property defining in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

There is an example in the article https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/transform-a-stream-with-ksql.html:

```
CREATE STREAM pageviews_transformed
  WITH (TIMESTAMP='viewtime',
        PARTITIONS=5,
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON') AS
  SELECT viewtime,
         userid,
         pageid,
         TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(viewtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') AS timestring
  FROM pageviews
  PARTITION BY userid
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

You can see that there is double partitions property defining. In WITH clause we define partitions count for brand new stream (topic). In GROUP BY clause - for incoming messages so as to be able to define to what partition send a message.

We created a stream with 5 partitions. Let's imagine that we have messages with 6 unique userid. In this case how will messages be distributed over that 5 partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITIONS` is the number of Kafka **topic partitions**

`PARTITION BY` defines which kafka **message key** is used during record production

> Let's imagine that we have messages with 6 unique userid. In this case how will messages be distributed over that 5 partitions

Via Kafka's `DefaultPartioner` class